# How to remove www from both http and https

Tags: htaccess

I've got an ecommerce site where we're have some reports (random) of the cart not operating correctly. I think it might be due to removing www not working with https

my current htaccess code looks like this:

```
# remove the www
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What do I need to do to also force this on https?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like the same situation covered on StackOverflow: [URL rewriting for different protocols in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634101/url-rewriting-for-different-protocols-in-htaccess)

Here is the code for removing the `www` from your hosts, regardless of HTTP or HTTPS protocol:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If you want to remove `www` and redirect to HTTPS the rule is much simpler.  See: [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```