# Shifting from no-www to www and browsers' password storage

Tags: dns, browsers, no-www

I created a website having user-registration system and invited my friend to join it. I gave him the link of `no-www` version: `http://mydomain.com` but now after reading [this](http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/) and [this](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/1637428313), I want to shift to `www.mydomain.com`.

But there's a problem. I saw that my browser is storing separate passwords for `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`. So in my friend's browser his password must have been stored for `no-www`. That means after I shift to `www` and next time he opens the login page, his browser wouldn't auto-fill the username and password fields and there will also be an extra entry (of `no-www`) in his browser's database of stored passwords.

Can this be avoided? Can I do something that will convey to browsers that `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` are the same website? I already have a CNAME record for `www` pointing to `mydomain.com` but it seems that search engines consider CNAME as alias but browsers consider them as different websites, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the browser software and not that of your website, a browser will store passwords for an exact match URL which means if they visit the `www` site then that's where the password will be saved for, this is the same case for 'most' cookie based sessions.

*Enforcing `www`*

You can prevent this problem reoccurring by enforcing `www` in the URL address, this means no one will ever be able to visit the site without `www` and if they do it will redirect them to the correct address - meaning that saved passwords and sessions based cookies will be saved only for the correct URL preventing any problems.

There are many ways of how you can enforce `www` and this is one common solution using Apache with `mod_rewrite`:

> SOURCE: [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects)
>
> Catch all and redirect non-www to www
>
> You should opt to use mod_write for redirecting all requests for non
>   www versions of your site because the $1 varible will catch page
>   names, so example.com/page1/ will automaticly redirect to
>   www.example.com/page1/.
>
> mod_rewrite:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. RewriteRule ^(.*)$
> http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

*People with saved passwords*

You may find that you have to ask your site visits to clear their saved cookies and forms within the browser they are using should any further problems occur.

Comment: Thanks. By saved passwords I meant the new feature of browsers to permanently save password ("Do you want to save password for this site?"). I realize I wasn't clear. It seems the best solution possible is to convey to the users that the website now is on www.