# I am changing my file extensions in URLs, how to keep my good SEO results?

Tags: seo, google, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a website with good SEO results. For design reasons I have to update the design and I have to change file names from `.html` to `.php`. But I keep my domain name!

What should I do in order to keep my good SEO results?

Comment: Try googleing on `mod rewrite` and `htaccess`.

Comment: see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects

Comment: I'd omit the file extension. So you won't have any problems if you switch to asp (or something else) in a few years

Comment: I wouldn't change the file extensions to php. Either omit them, or keep htm. Silently redirect to the appropriate php files on the server.

Answer (score 6):

Just redirect by 301 HTTP status all your old URLs to the new ones. If you only change file extension, you can do it easily with an *.htaccess* file (if you use Apache as a web server).
Put these lines in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.example.com$1.php
```

Of course, change `www.example.com` by your domain name.

By using 301 redirects, you lose a little bit of SEO value (PageRank) for your pages but this is the best option you have.

P.S.: like Geoff Jackson suggests in comments, if you can use URLs without file extensions, it will be a good option because you will get better user friendly URLs. The *.htaccess* code for this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: @Kos Further to this answer, you could go one better still and remove the file extension from the URL's altogether with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of these solutions:

- Keep the Current `.html` extension unchanged  for just frontend purpose and use Apache *.htaccess* file to proxify your requests so that. Add this to your *.htaccess* file to 
  work:

  > RewriteEngine on
  >   RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1.php

OR

- Why not just have the HTML pages parsed as PHP? That way you can get the best of both `php`  and `html`.

  > AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm