# What to do in Google Webmaster Tools when moving from root to www

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress

I've read tons of questions but I can't find the answer to this seemingly obvious issue.

I'm moving my WordPress site from `example.com` to `www.example.com` so that I can use CloudFlare. I did the change in WP and everything works fine, with `example.com` redirecting correctly.

Do I need to add the `www` site in GWT (and remove `example.com`) or will it keep tracking the website correctly thanks to the redirections?

Comment: You should add www. to GWT.

Comment: @bybe Thanks. Do I need to do anything more or GWT will simply consider it as a new site, and then I'll remove the `domain.com`?

Comment: Nope, Just ensure that your redirecting all requests as 301 or 302.

Comment: @bybe can you please copy your comment to an answer so that I can give it to you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*301 Redirects*

When adding the sub domain `www.` to an existing site you will need to ensure that all requests are redirected using a `301 permanent`, this can be achieved by using a simply [.htaccess rewrite command](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/47310/20604) that catches all requests from `non-www` to `www.`

*Adding non-www and www. to GWT*

You should proceed to add `www.` to Google Webmaster Tools since it'll be treated as a different site, however because you have the 301 in place Google rankings should be pretty much the same as the non-www.