# How can I disallow access to my website by its IP address?

Tags: htaccess, apache

I want my website to be accessible only by the domain name, not by the server’s IP address. How can I configure Apache to achieve this?

Below are the VirtualHost configurations of Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName not.configured
  DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost my.server.ip.address>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The primary problem you have is that you cannot divorce the domain name from the IP address. All Apache traffic arrives addressed to the IP address with the domain name in the packet header. Apache receives the packet and then uses the address in the packet header to locate the proper website. There are things that can be done, however, I suspect your answer is in the .htaccess file more than anything. I do have a blank site that all packets that do not have a domain name in the packet header go to. I would have to think on this a bit.

Comment: maybe the problem is in the firewall does not accept the ip port 80

Comment: @closenoc: that's irrelevant for web traffic. All modern Browsers use HTTP 1.1, which demands a "host" - header. This header contains the server name that the client requested data from. This value is based on the URL that is requested, and is not translated via DNS. Thus, it differs between requesting a file through a domain name and requesting it through an IP address. And Apache can handle requests differently based on this distinction.

Comment: @closetnoc: Perhaps OP is worried someone will try entering the IP in a browser to figure out who it belongs to. If you're interested in staying anonymous, that'll stop most people who don't have the ability to get a court order to identify the owner of the IP.

If someone is trying to access the site by its domain, obviously they already know whose site they're trying to access.

Comment: @Dreamer Still- the point I was making, regardless of the protocol and header, the request is wrapped and addressed by IP address not by domain name. Because of that, you can block IP based requests, and I understand why someone wants to do this, however, you cannot divorce the domain name from the IP address. Which was the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @flarn2006 You cannot divorce the domain name from the IP address. That was my point. It was just a comment. I can generally get the owner of an IP address or domain name regardless of any anonymous registration. A simple and appropriate request is all that is needed. The notion of needing a court order is a bit of a misnomer. No company wants any legal action when the request is reasonable and within the rules of the Internet. It costs too much and they did not make enough money off of the registration to do battle on your behalf. Resistance is about all you get.

Comment: @closetnoc Why would they give out information if they weren't required by law to do so? Receiving a court order doesn't mean you have to go to court; it just means someone else *has* gone to court and you need to comply. Requiring a court order wouldn't make it any harder for the ISP; it would only make it harder for the people who want to get their customers' information.

Comment: @flarn2006 Because long before the law comes into play, the rules of operating an Internet business such as domain registrar, ISP, webhost, and so on, where certain functions are required, the ability to perform that business can be removed quickly without the need of the law. Trust me- I know law fairly well. I am just saying that court order is the last step. A reasonable and well placed request is enough. *You* as a person would be easy to blow-off, but *you* as an entity with well communicated rights and counsel will get results. Private registration does not shield a bad doer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Empty Virtual Host**

With virtual hosting, all traffic is routed to an IP address and then Apache matches the hostname.  When virtual hosting using `NameVirtualHost` is enabled, the site that responds to the IP address is the first one listed in the Apache configuration file.

So you can use a null virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /dev/null
    ServerName *
    Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

I've not tested this so may need a tweak but if you put this first in your configuration then traffic to your IP address should return a 404 error.

You would then specify  your `VirtualHost` second.

**301 Redirect**

Alternatively, you could just redirect requests to the IP address to the preferred domain using a 301 redirect in your htaccess.

See: [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects)

for a list of rewrite rules.

Comment: Perfect! I have not checked your code of course, but it is not too far off from what I do. You explained it extremely well too! For those Apache installs that are not set-up for virtual websites (and there are some), this can be a bit trickier. That is what I was referring to with the .htaccess comment I made because it appeared that it was possibly a single site install- though I could be wrong.

Comment: I can not acess my website from both domain name and IP address after using the first solution. [warn] VirtualHost `my.ip.address:80` overlaps with VirtualHost `my.ip.address:0`, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive

Comment: Yes that is what I would expect if you did not setup `NameVirtualHost` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply redirect the user to the named host:

```
# Uncomment the line below if not previously added in the file
# RewriteEngine On

# Rule to redirect to the named host
# Replace [xx.xx.xx.xx] woth your host's IP address
# Replace [yourdomain.com] with your host's proper URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$
RewriteRule (.*) http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I didn't ttest this to see if it works or not, but at least it's an idea you can build on, for a proper solution.

Comment: I tried this in .htaccess but still redirect me to my domain name.

Comment: You cannot break the link between your IP and your domain host - unless you're on a machine behind a router which only redirects port 80 from the public IP to your private IP on the subnet - but even so, requests comming on port 80 on the public IP will nevertheless be routed to your machine. This is because all requests are comming into the webserver from the IP - the domain name is just an "easy to remember" alias of your physical IP address.