# Google Webmaster Tools- Do I need to mark my SSL domain as a duplicate of my non-SSL domain?

Tags: google-search-console, https, http, no-www

I have a Drupal 7 site served exclusively using SSL with the "bare" domain (no www).

But, I see that in Google Webmaster Tools, I can add the following:

- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`

I have added all of these for my site, accessed **Site settings**, and set it to *Display URLs as `example.com`*.

This is true for the `example.com` + `www.example.com` pair and the `https://example.com` + `https://www.example.com` pair. Do I need to do anything more to mark my `https` sites as duplicates of the non-https sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [SOURCE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console/68436#68436)
>
> *Add all variations of your site to WMT*
>
> While the site address move tool may not treat protocols, url changes
> and sub domains as new sites, the rest of Webmaster Tools does treat
> protocols and sub domains as separate sites. You should add all
> variations of your site, below is an example of my site BYBE added to
> WMT with all variations, you should do the same. (recommended by [John
> Mueller](https://plus.google.com/%20JohnMueller/posts) from Google, See comments below this answer).

[image: bybe multiple sites in webmaster tools]
<sub>(source: [bybe.net](https://www.bybe.net/files/pro-webmasters/bybe-multiple-sites-in-google-webmaster-tools.png))</sub>

> *301 redirects recommended by Google*
>
> If you plan to serve the website as partial ssl or complete then you
> should setup good redirects, as recommended by Google:
>
> > [SOURCE](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/site-move-with-url-changes?hl=en&ref_topic=6033084&visit_id=637462513557857177-2927252741&rd=1)
> >
> > **Prepare for 301 redirects** Once you have a mapping and your new site is ready, the next step is to set up [HTTP 301 redirects](/webmasters/answer/93633) on your server
> > from the old URLs to the new URLs as you indicated in your mapping.
> > Keep in mind the following:
> >
> > - **Use HTTP 301 redirects.**
> >   Although Googlebot supports several kinds of redirects, we recommend
> >   you use HTTP 301 redirects if possible.
> > - **Avoid chaining
> >   redirects.** While Googlebot and browsers can follow a "chain" of
> >   multiple redirects (e.g., Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3), we
> >   advise redirecting to the final destination. If this is not
> >   possible, keep the number of redirects in the chain low, ideally no
> >   more than 3 and fewer than 5. Chaining redirects adds latency for
> >   users, and not all browsers support long redirect chains.
> >
> > **Test the redirects.** You can use [Fetch as Google](/webmasters/answer/158587) for testing
> > individual URLs or command line tools or scripts to test large numbers
> > or URLs.
>
> *Setting up the redirect in Apache*
>
> Setting up redirects in Apache, ngInx, IIS is pretty straight forward,
> below is examples of redirecting 301 from HTTP to HTTPS in Apache2
> `.htaccess` file.
>
> > [**SOURCE**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects/47310#47310)
> >
> > #### Enforce SSL on specific pages and disable on rest
> >
> > This script will remove SSL on all other pages part from the login
> > page and register page, you can add more just use `|` as the separator
> > between file names.
> >
> > mod_rewrite:
> >
> > ```
> > RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
> > RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/(login|register)\.php [NC]
> > RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> > ```
> >
> > #### Enforce SSL on the entire site
> >
> > If you want to enforce SSL on the complete site then you can use
> > mod_rewrite to detect HTTPS off.
> >
> > mod_rewrite:
> >
> > ```
> > RewriteEngine On
> > RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> > RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> > ```
>
> *Sitemap changes*
>
> Since you are changing protocol you need to add a new property to
> Google as HTTPs, this will have no sitemap submitted as default, you
> will need to ensure that your sitemap contains all the new URLS and
> then submit it under the HTTPS property variation.

*You should also inform Google your preferred domain (variation):*

> [SOURCE](https://web.archive.org/web/20190621132912/https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en)
>
> Specify a preferred domain:
>
> - On the Search Console Home page, click the site you want.
> - Click the gear icon , and then click Site Settings.
> - In the Preferred domain section, select the option you want.

Comment: So even though I've enforced SSL on the entire site via .htaccess (every page redirects to `https://example.com`), I should still add `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` (seems like a waste of time adding and verifying all these versions) while identifying `https://example.com` as the preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Google Search Console (formerly known as Google Webmaster Tools) does not have a preferred protocol settings (though oddly Google Analytics does).

You should ensure you have 301 redirects to direct users and search engines to the preferred version (`https://example.com`) and not allow your site to be accessed in multiple ways without redirecting to the preferred method.

Adding all 4 variants of your site is recommended best practice in case a variant has issues, but with the correct redirects, only the preferred version will have any data.