# What to do with sitemaps when going HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: google-search-console

I recently switched my WordPress.org blog from http://myblog to https://myblog.com with redirections.

For a year, I only had `http://` addresses, so my 8 sitemaps (my blog is in French and in English) are submitted to the http URL.

What do I need to do with the sitemaps now that `https` is my main URL? 
Do I need to re-upload the sitemaps to HTTPS ? Do I leave them on the HTTP property ?

Might be useful to know that I created a "set" for my blog that contains `http://myblog`, `http://www.myblog`, `https://myblog`, and `https://wwww.myblog`

Thanks!

I read this, but it doesn't talk about sitemaps anywhere. [Moving from http to https - Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-google-search-console)

Answer (score 2):

If you've got 301 redirects in place and there are no http URLs left on your site, you edit your sitemaps and change all "http" references to "https". Then go into your preferred version of Search Console and resubmit any relevant sitemaps there. That way, you will see correct index status data for the preferred version of your site (because the index status is based on what's in your sitemap). There's no need to maintain or submit sitemaps for any other variant of your site if there is only one version actually serving: in that case, the sitemap you submit should contain all the canonical URLs you'd like to be in the index.

In other words, if your blog is serving only on https://example.com, you need a sitemap with all your pages in that form, submitted in that property in Search Console. Don't submit sitemaps for http://example.com, http://www.example.com, or https://www.example.com - because those are not canonical URLs, you don't want them in the index, and they won't index anyway (with 301 redirects in place).

You might also find it helpful to check out John Mueller's FAQ about https migrations:
https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/PY1xCWbeDVC

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is create and verify a new property for the https in Search Console (remember to set as default), then you need to create a new xml sitemap that points to your https URLs (upload it to the new property in GSC). Do the same to the robots.txt for the https website and include a sitemap link to the new https xml sitemap.