# SEO sitemap pending in Google after SSL change

Tags: https, sitemap, netlify

I have a site http://www.example.com
It has a valid site map at http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
The site is running through [netilfy.com](http://www.netlify.com)

I recently enabled SSL in Netlify, now all pages are redirected to the SSL version.

The problem I am having is that my submitted site map in Google Webmaster Tools stays as 'pending' and is never crawled. I resubmitted it today but it has been like that for many days.

[image]

Why is this and what do I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't added a new property in Google Search Console. Add your site again but this time using the HTTPS protocol, it is also recommended that you add all variations of your site, see below:

> [SOURCE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console/68436#68436)
>
> *Add all variations of your site to WMT*
>
> While the site address move tool may not treat protocols, url changes
> and sub domains as new sites, the rest of Webmaster Tools does treat
> protocols and sub domains as separate sites. You should add all
> variations of your site, below is an example of my site BYBE added to
> WMT with all variations, you should do the same. (recommended by [John
> Mueller][2] from Google, See comments below this answer).
>
> [image: bybe multiple sites in webmaster tools]
> <sub>(source: [bybe.net](https://www.bybe.net/files/pro-webmasters/bybe-multiple-sites-in-google-webmaster-tools.png))</sub>

Comment: See **domain properties** to add all variations of your site at once.