# Should I delete http property in search console after adding https version

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engines

I just started using SSL for my website. I have redirected all the urls from http to https. From some of the previous questions and answers I understand I should add https version of my site as new site in search console.

But should I delete the http property from console? Is deletion good from seo standpoint?

P.S. My site is quite new with just 60 urls (http urls) indexed so far

Comment: Once you have a 301 redirect in your site from http to https version, the old search console property (http) will stop registering some data so the answer is yes, you should remove it. Nontheless I will wait a few weeks before deleting it in order to wait till the new property gets all the data.

Comment: @Emirodgar that's incorrect, Google recommends that you add all variations to Google Search Console, see linked question.

Comment: @SimonHayter My question was precisely on whether I should "delete" the http version or leave as it. I had already seen the previous question you had linked. But I think there was no decisive indication or reply that stated whether to delete or not the http version.

Comment: @SimonHayter thanks for the link. If you are using only the https version of the site, there will be no data in the http GSC profile. What's the point on having both of them?

Comment: @Kannan no need to add another question simply because you want help deciding which advice is more suitable for your needs. Its like asking, Google recommends that I keep all variations, should I delete them? that's really not a real question, its asking for discussion and opinions which is off-topic on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: @Emirodgar I know what your saying and it seems odd to add all variations despite no data will be collected in the other 3 properties but fact is Google recommends that you add all variations. I believe by adding all variations it allows you to spot errors with content being indexed on the wrong variation.

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate, but actually it is not answered, even in the "canonical" question. see [this comment](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console#comment93366_79684) for example

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary, you only have to change the *default URL* from **http** to **https**.

[image]

Comment: Where exactly on search console is this possible. I think the change from http to https is not possbile on an existing propery on search console (based on previous discussions)/

Comment: I think this screenshot is taken from Google Analytics