# Moving from HTTP to HTTPS in Google Search Console (October 2023)

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, https, duplicate-content, http

In Google Search Console I have previously created property with HTTP protocol and indexed my site.
Now I have full 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS for my site with just couple of pages.
Have ROBOTS.TXT , SITEMAP.XML and all LINKS list HTTPS pages.

Now I want MANUALLY INDEX some pages in GSC under new property with HTTPS protocol, but GSC says "**Page is not indexed: Duplicate, Google chose different canonical**" and points canonical to HTTP pages.

In the HTTP property when I try manual index, GSC says `Page redirect error ...`

My pages have changed and I can not wait 6-18 months to Google reindex is alone.
Have read all articles on Stockexchange as well "**[Moving from HTTP to HTTPS in Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console)**"
and "**[Moving from HTTP to HTTPS in Google Search Console (May 2019)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console)**", but there is no solution.

**Question:**
I want to delete old index with HTTP permanently (temp removals in GSC do not solve the issue) and create new manual index request for HTTPS.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why can't you wait months?  In the meantime, users that click to your HTTP site from Google will get redirected to your HTTPS site.

Answer (score 1):

Surely what you need to do is

1. If you have access to .htaccess, then rewrite the `http` pages to `https`.
2. Put in a `canonical` tag that points to `https`

Comment: In the first paragraph they said they're already redirecting from HTTP to https

Comment: Hi, I do not have .htaccess but all **pages** , **canonical** and **links** point to HTTPS. And still no success.

Comment: To additionally clarify: I'm stuck in a dead loop. **HTTP** index is not possible as pages are redirected (Redirect error), and **HTTPS** index is not possible as duplicates exist (Google sets canonical to http). @rohit

Comment: If Google is indexing the HTTP, they are indexing the copy they crawled before you redirected it.  That isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Well, no, it is a bad thing, as I have changed my pages and now I can not index them under HTTPS. @stephen  Regards.

Comment: Changed your pages so much that they are now ranking for the wrong keywords?