# Redirect Everything After slash (/) to another directory

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm sure this is an easy thing to do but I can't seem to find the answer!

I'm trying to redirect `https://carddav.example.com/MYUSERNAME` to `https://carddav.example.com/remote.php/subdomain/addressbooks/MYUSERNAME/contacts` where MYUSERNAME can be anything.

The current RewriteRule I have attempted looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://carddav.example.com/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/$1/contacts/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Please try something before posting here. If it doesn't work we can help you. [This canonical question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects) may be useful to you.

Comment: The closest I've come is this but it doesn't redirect properly `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://carddav.example.com/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/$1/contacts/ [R=301]`

Comment: Good enough to get the question re-opened!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single `RewriteRule`. The trick here is to only check for valid username characters, not *everything* (ie. `.*` - I wouldn't have thought your usernames could literally be *anything*?). This would also be more efficient since not every request will match and be processed.

For example, assuming your usernames can only consist of upper/lowercase letters and numbers then:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])$ /remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/$1/contacts [R=301]
```

This is very similar to your initial attempt. Note that the `RewriteRule` pattern in per-directory .htaccess files does not begin with a slash, however, if this rule was used in your server config then it would!

This also naturally avoids the rewrite loop since "/remote.php/carddav..." will not match as a valid username (specifically `.` and `/` would fail to match).

You could also limit the length of the username, to say between 4 and 20 characters...

- `^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20})$`.

If you needed to match any character except a slash (a slash would surely break your destination URL?) then you could use a pattern like:

- `^([^/]+)$`

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed through one heck of a lot of perseverance. I really should take the time to learn all of mod_rewrite at some point in time…

In short I solved the redirect loop with the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/remote.php/
```

The above condition basically matches everything that isn't remote.php/ANYTHING_HERE

I then used the above RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav/addressbooks%{REQUEST_URI}/contacts [R=301]
```

The RewriteRule is almost identical to my previous comment with the difference being it uses the actual request (which is a username in my case and includes a slash - / - so does not need one at the end of addressbooks).

The end result is a full permanent redirect and a handy short URL for me to use when accessing carddav.

Comment: A slight problem with this approach is that you are potentially matching too much (ie. _everything_) or not enough (eg. the pattern matches an empty username) which is unnecessary and less efficient. If you restrict the pattern then you can do this with a single `RewriteRule` and still avoid rewrite loops. I've added an answer.