# How to add the ‘www’ prefix to my domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, amazon-ec2, amazon-aws

I am trying to add `www` to my domain.
I have the custom PHPcode on live server.
I have workout GoDaddy forward options also but still my domain not forward.
I have a site designed in Core PHPand was wondering how to automatically Add the `www` prefix to my domain?
I have already tried with GoDaddy Forward but still my domain can't redirect:
Also *.htaccess* not working.

My server configurations:

- GoDaddy + Amazon ec2 (Httpd(RHEL))
- mod_rewrite enabled
- Enabled in *etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf*: `AllowOverride All`

How do I change `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com` for my site?

Comment: Did you add www in Wordpress Address URL and Site Address URL ??

Comment: Surprisingly to me, I could not find another question on this site that asks this directly and has a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

From [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects) contributed by [bybe](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/20604):

#### Catch all and redirect non-www to www

You should opt to use mod_write for redirecting all requests for non www versions of your site because the $1 varible will catch page names, so `example.com/page1/` will automaticly redirect to `www.example.com/page1/`.

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

mod_alias:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</If>
```