# Issue in webmaster tool

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers

I have created a site with domain name 
 `https://www.example.com` 
but the site had many problems so I created a new fresh site and removed the previous one. This time I chose the domain name as  `https://example.com` Now the problem is that in my webmaster tool both the version are available. What should I do to remove previous one or make them one?

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove any, it is not recommended by Google. You should add all variations to Webmaster Tools as suggested by Google. You then inform Google the [preferred domain](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en).

You should also take steps to ensure that when people or bots visit `www.` they are redirected to `non-www`, the redirection process in Apache is pretty straight forward and I recommend that you check out [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects). If using IIS or NGINX then search our site you should find many related questions and answers.

If you still want to remove the domain even through it is not recommended then you can do so by:

[image: delete domain from Google Webmaster Tools]

- Search Console
- Click management property on the domain you wish to delete
- Click delete property