# htaccess redirect a subsub directory to new domain same structure

Tags: htaccess, redirects

Any idea how to redirect from old domain  to new one using `htaccess`:

`domain.example/A/B/some-file-bb-cc`

to

`new-domain.example/A/B/some-file-bb-cc`

Comment: This question has already been asked here a number of times, and also covered in the community wiki [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects) (at the bottom).