# How to update my website's URL in Google from www to non-www

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, url

I am having trouble updating the URL of my first uploaded website that I made from scratch. I have changed the the URL and have submitted to Google, but when I type in the name 'example' into Google my old website URL (`www.example.com/example/`) is displayed with the old title and meta tags. However when I type in `example.com`, which is the new URL, it shows first and it's the correct website with the correct tags and title.

How can I make the old URL `http://www.example.com/example` to just `example.com`? I have taken out the `www.` from the new URL, would that be a problem?

Comment: If you haven't already, you'll need to `301` redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com` and set your [Preferred Domain](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en) in Google Webmaster Tools/Search Console.

Comment: @dan thanks for the answer! most of the 301 redirect are on new pages to old pages how can I redirect 'www.example.com' to 'example.com'?

Comment: If you're redirecting the `non-www` URLs to `www` URLs, but your preferred URL is the `non-www`, then you'll need to replace those redirects with one of the examples under [Catch all and redirect www to no-www](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an apache server, you can add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```bash
# Enable Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Check if we're on the www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
# If the previous condition is true, redirect to non-www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above code will redirect everything to a non-www version of your URL

[More info >>](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.htaccess/1550/rewriting-and-redirecting/7550/redirect-non-www-to-www-subdomain-and-vice-versa#t=201608080132595490257)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, having troible implementing the statements. Do I put the www.example.com after the www\.?

Comment: No. Don't change anything about the code. It's a generic redirect.