# Is a CNAME from the domain apex to the www record the correct way to configure a site to use the WWW version?

Tags: seo, dns, 301-redirect

Let's say I own `example.com` and want to use `www.example.com` as the default.

I thought I could do this by using an A record to point the `www` version to the IP and using a `CNAME` record to point the naked domain to the `www` version.

Like this:

```
www.example.com A 14400 192.0.2.123
example.com CNAME 14400 www.example.com
```

Two questions:

- I've been apprised that the DNS entries above won't work because you can't `CNAME` a naked domain to a subdomain. Is that correct?
- If that's true - and I still want to use `www` as the default - should I just leave the A entry as is and 301 the naked domain to the `www` domain? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects)

Comment: I appreciate the link, but I don't think it addresses either of my questions. To clarify, I'm not asking HOW to configure this as much as IF I should use this configuration.

Comment: You can not have a `CNAME` record at apex (`example.com` in your case) based on how CNAME is defined, it can not coexist with any other record (except DNAME and RRSIG), while the apex already has `SOA` and `NS` records even if you do not see them. You typically do the opposite, add an `A` record on apex, and have `www` be a `CNAME` to apex. It is just one way to do things among others.

Comment: PS: `123.456.789` is not a valid IPv4 address, even from very far. I edited your question to replace that.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions--and the configuration you proposed (A for the apex and CNAME for the www) will work. But, can you explain why this is better than the version I proposed (A for the www and 301 the apex to the www)? Not second-guessing. Just trying to understand the pros/cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been apprised that the DNS entries above won't work because you can't `CNAME` a naked domain to a subdomain. Is that correct?

Yes, as stated in comments, you can't create a `CNAME` record on the domain apex, ie. `example.com`. Trying to do so can cause problems later.

You would typically do this the other way round. For example:

```
example.com.  A      14400  192.0.2.123
www           CNAME  14400  example.com.
```

Alternatively, you could create `www` as another `A` record to the IP address. But this is unnecessary if they point to the same place - it would require repeating the IP address.

These DNS records simply direct traffic to `example.com` or `www.example.com` to your server. Both are "equal". Neither one or the other is the "default".

To make one or other "default" you need to 3xx redirect one to the other.

> to use www as the default - should I just leave the A entry as is [for www] and 301 the naked domain to the www domain?

You would still need to create a DNS `A` record for the "naked" domain, otherwise it simply won't resolve (it won't reach your server). And then you can implement the 301 redirect.

However, implementing `A` (domain apex) + `CNAME` (www subdomain) would generally be preferable to `A` (domain apex) + `A` (www subdomain) as it's arguably easier to maintain. Although functionally it would be the same.

---

*Aside:* There is another (middle) step not covered here that also needs to be done in order to configure a site for `example.com` and `www.example.com`. The webserver itself needs to be instructed to accept requests for both. On a shared host, this will all be done for you. (For instance, you can't simply point a domain at a webserver - with a DNS `A` record - and expect that webserver to respond as you expect.)

Comment: This is very helpful--particularly the aside (which I would not have guessed). Many thanks.