# Does Google Domains offer path fowarding (as opposed to redirecting the entire domain)?

Tags: dns, domain-forwarding, google-domains

I have a URL `www.first.example` and I want to forward `www.first.example/test` to `www.second.example`. Is this possible to do in Google Domains?

UPADTE:

https://example1.com (OG site)
https://test.example1.com (Domain I want https://example2.com to redirect to)

https://example2.com (new site redirects to https://test.example1.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

Redirecting/fowarding a domain can be done within Google Domains at {your domain} > Website > Forward Domain (or Edit Forwarding).

For more info, see [Google's reference](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en).

#### Old Answer (now irrelevant)

> This is not possible by design.
>
> DNS servers are only meant to resolve hostnames to IP addresses. Once the request reaches *your* server (i.e. www.example1.com's IP address), you can route/redirect requests from **/test** to anywhere you want ([www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com)).

Comment: Just to add to this, a web server is needed to preform the redirect, so check out some of our questions about [redirects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=redirect+is%3Aq) - for example [commonly used Apache htaccess redirects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects).

Comment: Most DNS registrars offer forwarding services in addition to registration and DNS services.   In fact [Google domains offers forwarding services](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en).   They run web servers to do these redirects for you.   The question is whether those forwarding services support separate forwarding of specific paths rather than forwarding the whole domain.  Saying that it is not possible by design is wrong.  Their service is designed to offer redirects.

Comment: The question could use more clarification. As I understood it, n3o is asking about forwarding a specific path on one domain to another domain. That is outside the scope of DNS (i.e. not possible by design). At most, a DNS (Google Domains in this case) can only forward entire domains.

Comment: DNS can't forward anything: neither full domains, nor paths.   A web server is required for doing either.  My point is that because they offer forwarding, Google domains must be running web servers.  They may not have the functionality to forward paths, but it isn't because of limitations of DNS.

Comment: Semantic arguments aside, I believe we're on completely different pages (no pun intended, ha!). I've used Google Domains extensively. Google Domains *can* forward entire domains with the paths optionally included. What it *can't* do, is forward *one specific path* on one domain to another domain, because pathname routing is not handled at the DNS level (which is what Google Domains is for). Again, the question requires more clarification, because we do not yet know *exactly* what n3o is wanting to accomplish. I made my best guess while trying to interpret what n3o was originally asking.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! So yeah, some things changed since I posted the question. I think what I wanted initially could be done through synthetic records in google domains (I could be wrong) but it looks like they removed that. So I decided to switch to using a subdomain instead. What I have now is this: update above.